# Display MA from different time frame

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

is it possible to display MA from time frame eg. `D1` on `H4`?

I would like to see MA D1 `1:1` on H4. Using `security(tickerid, "1D", close)` is not what I seek.

Please check the example:

Here is MA20 on D1
I drew the yellow line on MA20

[image]

and then I change interval to `H4`

[image]

The yellow line shows MA20 from D1.

This is my problem: is it possible to write script, to show this MA20 from D1 on different time frames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `security()` function is exactly what you are looking for.

Instead of feeding it with `close`, you can actually pass an expression like `sma` there.

```
//@version=4
study("My script", overlay = true)
ma_20 = sma(close, 20)
ma_daily = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", ma_20, barmerge.gaps_on)
plot(ma_20, color=color.green)
plot(ma_daily, color=color.red)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this is not what I need :( Look here please https://www.dropbox.com/s/5znh4t8tih5pybv/tv.png?dl=0

I know that this is somehow possible but ... how? hmm

Comment: It looks like you want to have `gaps_on`. Please see my edit. I slightly modified the `security()` call.